# Given a list of numbers in random order, write an algorithm that works in O(nlog(n)) to find the kth smallest number in the list

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I have write this algorithm but i am not sure that this is correct or not please help me to solve this problem, i am beginner in python programming language.

```
for n in maxN:
     alist = range(n)
     adict = {}
     for j in xrange(n):
         adict[j] = None
     random_index = random.randint(0, n-1)

     start1 = time.time()
     del_in_list(alist, random_index)
     end1 = time.time()

     start2 = time.time()
     del_in_dict(adict, random_index)
     end2 = time.time()

     start3 = time.time()
     empty(adict, random_index)
     end3 = time.time()

     y1.append(end1-start1-(end3-start3))
     y2.append(end2-start2-(end3-start3))    
 plt.plot(maxN,y1, "r--", maxN, y2)
```

plt.show()

Is this algorithm is correct if yes then
*how to improve this algorithm in linear?*

Comment: I don't think there is a linear time solution to the general case.  There might be an n*log(k) solution: maintain a heap, insert items into the heap and trim the heap back down to k items at each item of n.

Comment: By the way: posting 20 lines of uncommented pseudo-code is not the ideal way to discuss an algorithm.  I have no idea what this "code" is supposed to be doing.  Try summarizing the strategy at a high level (in a comment) and then drilling down into how different functions and snippets implement that strategy.

Comment: The best way to verify if an algorithm works is to test it. Especially, try write an [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) for it.

Comment: What about doing merge sort in ascending order and than getting "kth" element?

Comment: @JimDennis There is a linear time solution, though it's not exactly beginner-level. Google 'median of medians'.

Comment: @Sneftei: I think that O(n*log(k)) is considered O(n) when k is small relative to n.  Read the article on Landau notation to confirm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: 1. Given a list of numbers in random order, write an algorithm that works in to find the kth smallest number in the list. 

2. Can you improve the algorithm from the previous problem to be linear? Explain.   This is the problem which I'm solving.

Comment: @JimDennis O(n*log(k)) is O(n) if and only if k=o(e^n), which I see no reason to think is the case for the OP. But that's neither here nor there; the median-of-medians algorithm is not sensitive to k.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually an algorithm to find the Kth smallest/largest element in an unsorted list in a linear time.
In order to do it in an O(n*log(n)) complexity, all you have to do is sort the list, and then retrieve the nth element. something like :

```
x = sorted(your_list)
print x[n]
```

If you don't want the 1st element to be in position 0, just change n to n-1.

Answer (score 0):

The solution may go like this for linear algorithm(make a bit of changes)

```python
import random

#creating random list
l =list(range(1000))
random.shuffle(l)

a=min(l)
b=max(l)

ch = [0 for i in range(a,b)]

i=a
while i<=b:
    pos = l[i] - a
    ch[pos] = ch[pos] + 1
    i += 1
sum=0
pos = 0
k = int(input("enter the value of kth element to find"))
while sum<k:
    sum = ch[pos] + sum
    pos = pos +1

x= ch[pos-1] + a
print("%d is the K'th element of the list" % (x))
```